# How do I evaluate a random math operator?

Tags: ruby, operators, expression

I'm new to both Ruby and programming in general.
I've been trying to put together a little script that randomly creates math questions and works them out as well, however I'm having trouble generating a random math operator.

My script so far:

```
num = (1..10).to_a

num1 = num.shuffle[0]
num2 = num.shuffle[0]

op = %w{+ - = /} 
op1 = op.sample

puts w = "#{num1} #{op1} #{num2}"

puts "Your answer is:"
answer = gets()

solution = num1 + "what do I put here??" + num2

if answer.to_i == solution
  puts "Correct! The answer is #{solution}"
else
  puts "Incorrect, the answer is #{solution}"
end
```

I've managed to pick out a random operator but can't use it in the solution as it's a string.

Comment: Oh, you might change the title -- you solved the random operator problem, your problem was actually how to evaluate the string afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use symbols, and send it to an operand with an argument?

```
5.send(:+, 10)
```

For example:

```
> syms = [:+, :-, :*, :/]
=> [:+, :-, :*, :/]
> num1.send(syms.sample, num2)
=> 50
```

Why'd you use `sample` for the ops, but not the numbers?

Comment: Thanks! As I said I'm very new so I was just trying various methods to see how they work. I'll read up on send :)

Answer (score 2):

The magic word you're looking for is "[eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Ruby)".  Once [sorry, got interrupted at my desk] Once you have the string, you simply eval it to get the result:

```
expr = "42"+"+"+"54"
result = eval(expr)

irb(main):006:0> expr = "42"+"+"+"54"
=> "42+54"
irb(main):007:0> result = eval(expr)
=> 96
```

Comment: Eval? When you can use `send`, `eval` is a serious security risk. Because the data here could come from an external source, this is a security and performance risk (`eval` is much slower than `send`).

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh Well yeah, but I'm pretty sure we're not dealing with a serious security risk in this case.

Comment: Good point. I just wanted to mention it as one of those design rules that should supposedly never be broken. Sorry if I sounded a little critical there.